Does sub-sampling apply to digital to analog converters as well?
Sub-sampling is a known technique used in receiver's analog to digital converters (ADC). It allows the minimum sampling rate to be equal to twice the analog signal bandwidth instead of twice the highest frequency component in that signal.
Does the same principle apply to the digital to analog converters (DAC) on the transmit as well?

Yes, certainly.
Note that, in the same way that the ADC is sensitive to many unintended frequency bands (images), so too the DAC emits myriad images of the baseband spectrum.
With tight enough filtering to exclude those images/sidebands, this can be used (in either direction) to directly acquire/synthesize radio signals.
cnlohr has many excellent projects (and videos) explaining this, but the most recent one will do for starters: https://github.com/cnlohr/lolra

One of the neat tricks is, if you transmit a bitstream out on an SPI or I2S shift register, it causes aliasing at the sample rate, with images at F×3, F×5, F×7, etc. But, the neat part is it preserves the size/shape of the transmitted waveform at images/aliases up the spectrum. For Channel 3, the 65MHz signal was being refelcted around the 40MHz sampling rate. Harry Nyquist can go bite a lemon.
This technique gives an incredible amount of fidelity even in extremely poor situations, unintuitively so. You can create surprisingly precise signals way outside anywhere you would expect them.

The accompanying work (and video) goes on to illustrate just how powerful this is: using an MCU able to generate fairly high harmonics (100s of MHz), a particularly energy-sparse modulation mode (LoRa) is demonstrated over km of range, with nothing more than an MCU, battery and a bit of wire! ...And, needless to say, an abject, willful ignorance of all the sidebands the thing is also spewing out. :)
But again, cleaning that up with suitable filtering or conversion, one can make a proper and respectable transmitter, and such is the basis of many commercial devices.
